# Run `mvn appengine:set_default_version` without rebuilding?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, deployment

Our build takes a long time, even when nothing has changed. When I run `mvn appengine:set_default_version` it does a full build, which takes a few minutes.

Is there an easier way to call set_default_version, bypassing the build?

Comment: Only the cloud console.

Comment: @jirungaray, I believe your comment is the gist of the right answer, so can you please turn it into an answer (will need a bit more verbiage:-) so it can be upvoted and perhaps accepted?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As requested by @Alex :)

I do believe you could build a custom flow to just to call set version. But seems like a complete overkill.

Since you should be changing the default version every once in a while and not on every build (I hope), would't the UI on the cloud Console suffice? You just go to Compute > App Engine > versions and setup the default.

Be advised some people reported issues with the new UI where default version was not changed, so if that fails you might need to use the old app engine console.